# スプレットシートの内容をdiscordに送信するプログラムを作ったが、途中から送信されず、undefinedとなる

Tags: google-apps-script

**作ったもの**
スプレットシートの内容をdiscordのチャンネルに送信するシステムを作りました。

**問題点**
discordに送るチャンネルは多くて、実行すると現段階で170件ほどにメッセージが送信されるしくみになっております。（今後されに増えるみこみ）

そうすると、160件は送信できたが、10件は送信できてないみたいなことが起きます。（この件数の割合はバラバラ。無事にすべて送信できることもある。）
ちなみにエラーにはなりません。

件数が多いのでwebhookの取得に失敗したりするのでしょうか？
無事にすべてを送信するためにはどのようなことをするのが良いでしょうか？
アドバイスをよろしくお願いします。

**試してみたこと**
コードの最後に　console.log　で送信したものを見れるようにした。
途中から　undefined　となったが、webhookやtokenも間違ってるとは思えなかった。

**実際のコード**

```
function submit(){
  discord()
};

function get_value() {
  var sheet1 = get_sheet('https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/xxxxxxxxxxxx',0);
    //日付
    var datecoord = sheet1.getRange(2,3);
    var date = datecoord.getValue();
      //format
    var formatcoord = sheet1.getRange(3, 3);
    var format = formatcoord.getValue();

    
    //配信時間
    var messages_array = []; // initialize
    var lastRow = sheet1.getLastRow()-10;
    //console.log(lastRow);
  for (let i = 11; i <= lastRow; i++) {
    var timecoord = sheet1.getRange(i,6); 
    var haisintime = timecoord.getValue();
    var message = 'None'
    if (haisintime > 0) {
      var message = Function('var date = ' + date + '; var haisintime = ' + haisintime + '; return ' + format + ';')();
      } 
    
    messages_array.push(message); // push
  }
  return messages_array; // return
    
  
};

//googleスプレットシート  自動送信
function get_sheet(gss_url,sheet_num) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(gss_url);
  var sheet = ss.getSheets()[sheet_num];
  return sheet;
};

//googleスプレットシート　ライバーdiscord情報
function get_sheet2(gss_url,sheet_num) {
  var discord = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(gss_url);
  var sheet2 = discord.getSheets()[sheet_num];
  return sheet2;
};

function discord(message) {
    var sheet2 = get_sheet2('https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy',0);

    var messages = get_value();  // call get_value() at here

    var lastRow2 = sheet2.getLastRow();  //最終行取得
    
    for (let j = 2; j <= lastRow2; j++) {

      //webhook
      var webhookcoord = sheet2.getRange(j,3);
      var webhook = webhookcoord.getValue();

    //token
      var tokencoord = sheet2.getRange(j,4);
      var dtoken = tokencoord.getValue();

  　//channel
      var channelcoord = sheet2.getRange(j,2);
      var dchannel = channelcoord.getValue();

    //format
      const url        = webhook;
      const token      = dtoken;
      const channel    = dchannel;
      const text       = messages[j-2];
      if (text === 'None') {
        console.log(channel + " : 送信なし"); 
        continue;
      }

      
      
      const username   = 'Tokiプロbot';
      const parse      = 'full';
      const method     = 'post';

      const payload = {
          'token'      : token,
          'channel'    : channel,
          "content"    : text,
          'username'   : username,
          'parse'      : parse,
      };

      const params = {
          'method' : method,
          'payload' : payload,
          'muteHttpExceptions': true

      };
      Utilities.sleep(500);

    response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, params);

    //実行ログ
      console.log(channel + " : " + text); 
    }
    
}
```

**実行ログ内容**
セルの中身が0の時は送信しないので"送信なし"
〇〇はdiscordチャンネル名
以下のように途中からundefinedとなり送信できていない。

```
18:18:00    情報  〇〇〇 : 送信なし
18:18:00    情報  〇〇 : 送信なし
18:18:01    情報  〇〇〇 : 送信文XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX。
18:18:01    情報  〇〇〇 : 送信なし
18:18:01    情報  〇〇〇 : 送信なし
18:18:01    情報  〇〇〇 : 送信なし
18:18:02    情報  〇〇 : undefined
18:18:02    情報  〇〇〇 : undefined
18:18:03    情報  〇〇〇 : undefined
18:18:03    情報  〇〇〇 : undefined
18:18:04    情報  〇〇 : undefined
18:18:05    情報  〇〇〇 : undefined
```

**追加**
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: コードを読む限り実行ログで表示している `text` はスプレッドシートからの値なので、Discord への送信より手前の、スプレッドシートからの読み取り部分で問題があるんじゃないでしょうか。

Comment: @cubick  スプレットシートを何度も確認しましたが、問題はなさそうですね。何か問題があるとするとほかにあるでしょうか

Comment: `text` が `undefined` であるということは `messages[j-2]` が配列(`messages`)の範囲外アクセスになっているという事です(GAS の場合、スクリプトエンジンが V8 なので範囲外アクセスをしてもエラーにはなりません)。つまり `j-2` の値が `messages` の長さ(要素数)以上になった事を意味します。

Comment: ループして送信するにも限界があるということでしょうか？送信するデータを二回に分けて送信するなどの工夫が必要になるといった感じでしょうか？@metropolis

Comment: @zumo1224 sheet1 と sheet2 の構造がどの様になっているのか判らないのですが、プログラムを読む限り `lastRow - 11`(`messages` の要素数) と `LastRow2 - 2` の値が一致していない、という状態になっています。

Comment: **undefined**となったものを調べたところちょうど後ろの10個のチャンネルでした。sheet1とsheet2は編集で追加した画像のようになっていて、sheet1は日付やアカウントなどの情報を上のセルに書くためグラフを**10行**ずらしています。sheet2はwebhookが書かれているものですが、それは上から順に書かれている感じです。チャンネルに関しましては、まったく同じ数同じ順番に並んでいます。undefinedの数後ろからが**10個**ということもありおそらくこのずれが問題なのではないかと考えているのですが、どうでしょうか？@metropolis

Comment: @zumo1224 はい、その通りだと思います。

Comment: ありがとうございます。　試してみます。

Comment: やっと理由がわかりました。最終行取得の際にsheet1とsheet2 **-10**してるかしてないかでちがうためうまくいかなかったのですね。金曜日にプログラムを実行するので試そうと思います。@metropolis